# Rearrange autoLayout after changes during view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I have 2 TableViews *(one at top, other at bottom)* in Storyboard and auto-layout is set and working. For the TableViews, I am retrieving the data from database, thus it won't instantly display the TableView content. After retrieving data is completed, in `numberOfRowsInSection` I am changing the height of the TableView depending on the count.

```
 if tableView == self.TableView1 {
    count = tableView1Content.count

    if count != nil {
      let cellSize = 100

      switch count! {
         case 0:
           tableView.frame.size.height = CGFloat(0)
           break;
         case 1:
           tableView.frame.size.height = CGFloat(cellSize)
         case 2:
           tableView.frame.size.height = CGFloat(cellSize * 2)
         default:
           print("D")
           break;
      }
    }
}
```

So I can change the height of the TableView1. TableView2 has a 'top space to TableView1' of 10, but as the height change happens after the view is loaded, TableView2 doesn't adjust itself to keep the 'top space to TableView1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the frame size not the height constraint constant. You should connect height constraint (IBOutlet) and change the height, after change call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Here [example](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/animating-autolayout-constraints/) of animating constraints.

Comment: Which height constraint should I connect to the ViewController? Should I connect TableView2's 'top space constraint to TableView1' and manually add the difference? I got a bit confused about your constraint bit. All I want is TableView2 to keep its constraint to TableView1 even TableView1's height changes. I think you got me a bit wrong. (Let me clarify my question. I have  TV1 at top, TV2 at bottom; with TV2 having top spacing to TV1 of 10. I want TV2 to preserve its constraint when TV1's height changes

Comment: that's ok, just connect tv1 height constraint, and change it to desired value, after that the tv2 top constraint will change automatically... just don't forget to call `layoutIfNeeded()` after changing height value. You have height constraint set on tv1?